# What Google Analytics information do you find most useful?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on a google analytics dashboard for a CMS I've created. I'm trying to decide exactly what information to display to the user. So what information would you want to see at a glance (when you first log in) and what information would you want access to, but don't need to see every time you log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a customer? You might want to ask them.

The time spent on page is the most valuable.  You can see what pages result in reading and which pages are ignored.

The referrers and keywords is the next most valuable, because that tells you if your promotions are working or not, if you are getting the right audience.

Google analytics has some integration with adwords' analytics and that is on my periodid checklist as well.

Everything else depends on if you have a specific question in mind, like is it safe to start ignoring MSIE6 users, are there enough users of Opera visiting to care how things render for Opera, do I need to pay attention to international readers and add internationalization features to my website, etc.

Comment: I have, but many of my clients are unfamiliar with Google Analytics, and I'm looking to get input from as many people as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A:
Visits count (today, yesterday, this week, this month);
Page views, references, adwords effect;

B:
Bounce rate, effective keywords, browsers usage (in %)... stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's all about the $$.

The Adsense revenue for different pages and for different keywords.